# Changing NSToolbarItem image size in Mac Catalyst

Tags: swift, macos, ipad, mac-catalyst

When adding custom `NSToolbarItem` using `NSToolbarDelegate` I can't set the image of the icons. The problem comes when using default ones (SplitView or Share), which have a different size:[image: Example of NSToolbarItem with different image size]

Here's the example code for two of the items, one is the share one and the other is to add a new item. Please also note that in the share example I'm using `NSSharingServicePickerToolbarItem` and even I'm overriding the image it's still using the 'system' one.

```
        case .new:
            let item = NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: itemIdentifier)
            item.image = UIImage(systemName: "plus")
            item.label = "New Card"
            item.action = #selector(ViewController.didTapCreateNewToolbarButton(_:))
            item.target = nil
            toolbarItem = item
        case .share:
            let item = NSSharingServicePickerToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: itemIdentifier)
            item.image = UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
            item.label = "Share"
            item.action = #selector(ViewController.didTapShareToolbarButton(_:))
            item.target = nil
            
            toolbarItem = item
```

I've tried using `UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 8, weight: .medium)` but the result is the same.
I've also tried this solution: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/131364 but the result is an image taking the whole space available (bigger and pixelated).

So, how can I change the size/styles of those buttons? Would be great to be able to change both the system and my custom ones.

EDIT 1: This issue only appears when removing the title, which makes the toolbar more small in height and resizes properly the system buttons but not the other ones:

```
if let titlebar = windowScene.titlebar {
  titlebar.toolbar = toolbar
  titlebar.toolbarStyle = .automatic
  titlebar.titleVisibility = .hidden // <-- THIS
}
```

Comment: My issue was the images are way smaller. I fixed it with `toolbar.displayMode = .iconOnly`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue too, but there are a few things that have helped.

Firstly, creating the `NSToolbarItem` from a `UIBarButtonItem` helps with sizing, and also gives the outline on mouse over that most apps seems to have in their toolbar items.

Secondly, using `applyingSymbolConfiguration` on the `UIImage` allows you to tweak the size and weight.

Here is my code for creating a share button:

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")?.applyingSymbolConfiguration(.init(pointSize: 13.0, weight: .medium))
let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: image)
let toolbarItem = NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: .share, barButtonItem: button)
```

Here it is on the left compared to `NSSharingServicePickerToolbarItem` on the right.

[image: Share button comparison]

It’s pretty close — the size and weight are correct, but the colour is a little off. The same is true in light mode — the Catalyst button is a little less prominent. This does seem to just be a Catalyst thing though. If you compare icons in Messages (left) for example to Finder (right), you’ll notice a similar difference. Hopefully Apple will fix this odd discrepancy at some point.

[image: Message and Finder icon comparison]